# Display "Submit" button on original page after it is sent to another page

Tags: php, html

I have 2 web pages. One is called `web1.php` and the other is `web2.php`. I have a menu on the top of both pages that calls both pages through links.

I have to be able to pass and display the "submit" button that is pressed (there are 3 buttons, one called "Hi", "Hello", "Hola") in `web1.php` to `web2.php` and then clink the link for `web1.php` on my header and have it also display there when I return to that page "You previously pressed hi".

I can get it to display on `web2.php` but don't know how to get to display again after pressing the link.

**web1.php**

```
      <input type="submit" value="HI" name="HI"> 
      <input type="submit" value="HELLO" name="HELLO">
      <input type="submit" value="HOLA" name="HOLA">
```

**web2.php**

```
   if ( $_POST['HI'] )
   { 
      echo "called using the HI";
   }
   else if ( $_POST['HELLO'] )
   { 
      echo "called using the HELLO Button";
   }
   else if ( $_POST['HOLA'] )
   {  
      echo "called using the HOLA Button";
   }
```

Comment: `but dont know how to get to display again after pressing the link.` ?? What does this mean? What do you want?

Comment: Meaning I have to get "You pressed HI button" to display again on the original (web1.php) page after I press the link in web2.php that takes me back to the original page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session to save action when you click button in web1.php
**web2.php**

```
if ( $_POST['HI'] )
   { 
      $_SESSION['button'] = 'Hi';
      echo "called using the HI";
   }
   else if ( $_POST['HELLO'] )
   { 
      $_SESSION['button'] = 'Hello';
      echo "called using the HELLO Button";
   }
   else if ( $_POST['HOLA'] )
   {  
   //...same above
      echo "called using the HOLA Button";
   }
```

Then in your **web1.php** you can echo $_SESSION['button']

Comment: Do you want display message when you click button?

Comment: it works thanks, but the variable is now displayed on web1.php at all times. I only need it to appear after I select the link in web2.php and go back to it

Comment: in web1.php you should add condition `if(isset($_SESSION['button'])) {echo $message;}

Comment: and if you want display only one time, you can unset session in your condition

Comment: I put this if(isset($_SESSION['button']))
   {
   echo $_SESSION['button'];
   } and HI is being displayed still

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['button'])) { echo $_SESSION['button']; unset($_SESSION['button'];}

Comment: i get a syntax error, should there be a comma somewhere

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['button'])) { echo $_SESSION['button']; unset($_SESSION['button']);}` This is correctly code

Comment: never mind, I was missing the closing ) in ($_SESSION['button']; updated it to ($_SESSION['button']);